# jQuery balancing exclusive and inclusive form options?

Tags: jquery, forms

Has anyone found a good method to balance option lists, such that both can modify the other? I have a list of `trims`, and `model_numbers`, and either one of these can result a one to one match.. If however, there is no one to one match, I'd like `trim` to narrow down `model_numbers` and vise-versa. I don't ever want incompatable options...

I can roll my own solution but is there anything like a jQuery framework that allows me to better customize this stuff?

Comment: I may be tired but I don't follow your question. Where do you get the select(?) options from and what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: from aJax. Rather than using trim/model_number, lets use Make, Model, I want it so someone can pick from model Civic and it be determined that it is Honda, and only Honda is available. If they start and select Honda, the other list should clear down to just show Models of Honda, etc. I want to keep them intuitively balanced, requiring minimal input of users.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know of any jquery framework to handle dynamically cascading select lists but From what it sounds like you have it repopulating the lists via ajax on change.  With that your probably about 80% of the way there to your own solution.